# How can I reliably cancel a compositionstart event?

Tags: javascript, ime

When only targetting Google Chrome, is it possible to cancel the compositionstart event? According to [this draft](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-compositionstart) it is cancelable, however, when using `e.preventDefault()` as such

```
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener('compositionstart', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Chrome still begins a composition when pressing `´` for example.

I currently have a reasonably reliable way of stopping this by using

```js
document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener('compositionstart', function() {
    this.blur();
    
    setTimeout(() => this.focus(), 0);
});
```

```html
<textarea>Spam ´ here</textarea>
```

As long as my textarea does not contain any breaks, this 'cancels' the compositionstart event when pressing `´`. My problem right now is that if I spam the `´` key for a few seconds, my method does not always cancel the event and this causes a `´` to appear.

What I'm doing also feels very hacky, so I was wondering if there is a good, possibly cross-browser, way of stopping the compositionstart event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that a (also hacky) solution against spamming was increasing the timeout to 20 milliseconds. This timeout should be short enough that the user won't notice the blur and refocus, but it's long enough to stop the spamming.

If I store the selection and range when the compositionstart event is fired, I can then reuse them after the blur, so that I won't get weird side-effects that I was originally having. For my original case of a `textarea` this solution does not work, because for this a custom implementation of the `window.getSelection()` method is needed. However, it does work for a `div` with `contenteditable` enabled.

Anyways, this code works for me in Chrome 84 and Firefox 78:

```js
document.querySelector("#root").addEventListener('compositionstart', function () {
  let sel = window.getSelection();
  let range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

  this.blur();

  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();

  setTimeout(() => {
    sel.addRange(range);
  }, 20);
});
```

```html
<div id='root' contenteditable="true" style="outline: none">
  <p>Spam ´ here</p>
</div>
```

I'm not very satisfied with the solution, but I've not found anything better yet. Hopefully someone else will find a more valid way of going about this.

This method does not work on phones, which fire the compositionstart event when the `div` receives focus.

Comment: this code help me in chrome but it's not work on fireFox

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Another way I could bypass this unfortunate limitation, is by briefly setting the input to readonly. Just a few ms.
This has the advantage to be cross-browser as far as I tested: on Chrome, Firefox and Safari (not tested on mobile).
Here are my 2 event handlers

```js
    onCompositionStart (e) {
      e.preventDefault() // Does not work.
      e.target.setAttribute('readonly', true)
    },
    onCompositionUpdate (e) {
      setTimeout(() => e.target.removeAttribute('readonly'), 200)
    }
```

Comment: Cool to see different solutions to this problem. It has been a while since I worked on this, but I saw that since my original question came out, the beforeinput event was introduced in all major browsers. Have you looked into that event, and would using it be a more robust approach towards solving the original question?