# How do i prevent dead keys to be displayed in a input

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Recently i made an input script where you can only write numbers and have a total length of 5. But some keys of code "Dead" still appear when pressed.How do i prevent the key to even show in the input box?

Here is the function to make it only numeric:

```js
public restrictNumeric(e) {
  if (e.which) {
    let input = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (e.which == "Dead") {
      console.log("Test")
    }
    return /[\d]/.test(input);
  }
  return false
}
```

Here is the Html:

```html
<input matInput placeholder="Ex. 447" formControlName="NumTag" type="number"
       onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==5) return false;"
       (keydown)="restrictNumeric($event)">
```

Comment: check this link will fix your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204395/how-can-i-reliably-cancel-a-compositionstart-event