# How do I disable text composition in an html textarea when on android?

Tags: android, webview, dom-events

I am using the input event on a textarea to apply some logic that mutates the value of the textarea. This works as expected in local dev environment in a browser.

However, my target platform is android. On this platform, I'm noticing that instead of event.inputType being `insertText`, sometimes it is `insertCompositionText`. Android is apparently trying to be efficient by not actually mutating the textarea's value until you press space. How can I disable this behavior?

I found someone in a similar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63204395/how-can-i-reliably-cancel-a-compositionstart-event) who tried to use blur and focus events quickly. I can't use this because (1) it's hacky, hope there is a better solution (2) it resets the cursor position and degrades the user experience.

For reference, using ionic vue, but this is just an html `<textarea>`:

```
<textarea v-model="input" @input="onInput" />
```

```js
onInput(event) {
   console.log("onInput", event);
   //more logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to handle this issue by adding a hidden password input and route all the focus, events and value of my text input to the password input

The browsers will not show any predictive for password inputs and no `insertCompositionText` anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  That behavior comes from the keyboard, which is a separate app on Android.  Not implementing the composing text functionality correctly will likely screw it up, breaking autocomplete, tap to correct, and the delete key, which all behave much differently due to composing text.  It might even break normal typing-  the idea of composing text is that it's temporary until you make it permanent.  If so, when it does autocorrect on space it would assume the old stuff is deleted and recommit the entire word, causing duplication.

Comment: Then can I update the composition text somehow?

Comment: Possibly.  If you replace it with composing text as well.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: A.d.d. p.e.r.i.o.d.s. b.e.t.w.e.e.n. e.a.c.h. c.h.a.r.a.c.h.t.e.r. l.i.k.e. t.h.i.s.